How do I prevent circular dependencies in a general tree?
I have a class in c# called Pose. Its functionality is not really important, but it contains as fields another Pose called _parent, and a List called _children. In the setter for the _parent, I need to make sure that setting the parent doesn't cause a circular dependency, as that would end up causing infinite recursive loops in other methods.
public Pose Parent
{
    get => _parent;
    set 
    {
        if (WouldCauseCircularDependency(value)) throw new ArgumentException("Cannot set a parent that causes a circular dependency");

        _parent?._children.Remove(this);

        _parent = value;
        _parent?._children.Add(this);
        MarkPoseDirty();
    }
}

bool WouldCauseCircularDependency(Pose potentialParent)
{
    return false; // TODO
}

How can I implement my WouldCauseCircularDependency() method to prevent this?
I am not too sure of the logic required for this.
EDIT: Maybe I have answered my own question here, but do I simply need to check if the potential parent is already a child (or grandchild etc) of the current pose?

Are you asking how to check this._children.Contains(potentialParent)? If so, does each object have unique keys? If so, I would just use the Any Linq method return this._children.Any(q => q.Key == potentialParent.Key).

No, i need to know if setting the this._parent equal to value would cause a circular relationship between nodes in the tree. That would cause an infinite loop, as i have methods that iterate through the children, calling the same method on each of the children. The edit was basically me asking if the way to do this is to check if the potential parent is already downstream of the current Pose. Ie, is a child of this, or a child of any children, or a child of THEIR children etc (i think the terminology is descendent?).

As per @FelixCastor clarification, you first need to tell us how to determine that two Pose objects are the same. Can we just use the default comparer, like poseA == poseB? Or does it have a key, such as an ID, that could be used to compare? Maybe share more of the Pose class and we can help you figure that out.

Yes Pose a == Pose b is fine. I am using the Pose class to emulate unity's transform class, but without needing to instanstiate game objects and with less overhead. Im using it to track the relative positions of each node in the tree to the parent transform.

Yes. Think of it as two operations, detach and attach. After you detach a branch of a tree, you have two separate trees. Now it is about attaching one tree to the other, so attaching to itself is definitely wrong.
Implementation-wise

option 1 is to only check itself and the children recursively for not being the new parent
option 2 is to literally detach from old parent and instead check the new parent for being present in the remaining nodes of the main tree.


I think the naive approach could get you started. If a node can be a parent, you will need to search all children and children's children etc. So that implies a couple tools you will need. A while loop and a queue of unvisited children. If the datastructure is just the asignments and you don't have a foreign key hidden somewhere, you will need to traverse the graph. If you had a flat list of items and foreign keys, this would be much simpler.
I'm going to make the assumption each item has a unique key to differentiate items.
bool WouldCauseCircularDependency(Pose potentialParent)
{
    
    var queue = new Queue<Pose>();
    foreach(var child in _children)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(child); // load up direct descendants to check.
    }

    while(queue.TryDequeue(out var current))
    {
        if(current.Key == potentialParent.Key)
        {
           return true; // can't be a parent.
        }
        
        foreach(var child in current.Children)
        {
           queue.Enqueue(child); // add the next level of descendants.
        }
    }

    return false; // all descendants checked and potential parent wasn't found.
}


Ah i get you. There is no key, simply using this == potentialParent is fine. Basically just check that the potential parent is not already downstream of the Pose? I have a method that does that already, so that would be very straightforward
